# reset random seed in CNTK

Tags: python, cntk

Is there a way to reset the randomness of CNTK?

The API for [cntk.random](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.random.html) shows seeds in the constructors of random operations. Can I change the seed after construction? I'm looking for functionality like this:

```
b = C.random.normal((1,), seed=0)
b.eval(device=C.cpu()) # 0.2341
b.eval(device=C.cpu()) # 0.1294
b.reseed(0)
b.eval(device=C.cpu()) # 0.2341
```

Unfortunately, I'm using b in many places in my graph. I want all of these operations to receive the same randomness again. If I simply define a new random variable `a = C.random.normal((1,), seed = same_as_b)`, then it's not integrated into my graph.

Comment: Hmmm, what kind of neural architecture would call for this? Cause we can building static graphs right?

Comment: In any case, based on what i understand, there's no such mechanism to reset the random number generator in the python API.

Comment: For architectures this might not be so important. But for debugging and testing it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Redefining the random number generator seem to do the trick for me.

```
import cntk as C


a = C.random.normal((1,), seed=0)
print(a.eval())  # 0.2925366
print(a.eval())  # 1.6854208
a = C.random.normal((1,), seed=0)
print(a.eval())  # 0.2925366
print(a.eval())  # 1.6854208
```

In any case, there's no such mechanism to reset the random number generator in the python API once its defined.

Comment: Sure, if you define a new random tensor with the same seed, it will give you the same series of random numbers. I have to reset the original tensor, because I'm using it in other places in my graph. Creating a new random variable would mean reconstructing the entire graph. I guess that would be possible, but it's a huge overhead